Why are my front brake brakes locking up?
I have a 2001 dodge ram 1500. A couple years ago I put a new master cylinder and brake booster in it. About 2 months ago my front passenger side brakes started grabbing real harm and burning real bad. I ended up replacing the brake hose and caliper on that side and the problem stopped. About a week or so later the other side started doing the same thing so I replaced the caliper and brake hose on that side as well. And bled the front brakes but the backs did not get bled because the bleeder valves are rusted pretty bad and I’m afraid I’ll snap them.  I drove it for about a week and noticed both sides started to slightly grab. The problem started get worse over the next week after that. It ended up eating the new brake pads down so I replaced the brake pads and noticed the caliper pistons were very hard to press in. I put the new pads on just to see what would happen and sure enough they were grabbing hard and overheating bad. The back brakes are perfectly fine and the brake pedal feels completely normal. Can anybody help me with this issue? Could the fact that I didn’t bleed the back brakes be causing an issue this big? If so why are the backs acting fine and the fronts are locking?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! T

Sounds like the pedal adjustment rod locknut has come loose and has allowed the pushrod to tighten up so there is no free play, thereby essentially like keeping your foot on the pedal, keeping pressure from releasing from the front brakes back into the Master Cyl. You need to check for free play/loose locknut at the pedal pushrod. You can check if pressure is holding by pushing the brakes, trying to spin the wheel and if tight, open the bleeder valve to see if it releases and the wheel spins freely. It could also be that the booster rod adjustment is incorrect, but check the pedal rod first.
